# Allow network connection to a specifc app

Tags: android, iphone, network-programming

I am developing a application for mobile (iPhone and Android) maps based for a company. The company has deployed a wireless network to allow, by subscribing, internet access.

The idea of the mobile app is to give internet access only to that specific app to any ones that have it. In other words, company wants to allow to application to connect to this network.

My question is: is it possible to give access only to a specific application and what would be the most appropriate way? Is the app that "recognize" that network or network is in charge of give access to that specific app? 
Any suggestion is very appreciated.

Comment: What type of wireless network is it? WiFi?

Comment: Also, another point of confusion that's stopping me from upvoting your question right now: should the whole device get regular internet access when the app is installed on the device? Or should only the app _itself_ be able to use the connection?

Comment: the network is a wifi service offered (by paying) for the company. the idea is that by the that app and ONLY the app, users can see some information using the internet service without having a pay plan, only to know some basic information about the company and its services. thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, a regular WiFi network won't have any facilities to allow a single application to access it. The mobile device OS associates itself with the WiFi network, and it will allow all applications to access it.

You could, however, use a proxy server that requires authentication. You could then build the authentication keys (for example, a client certificate) into the application such that only the application will be able to communicate through the proxy.

Comment: So the ideas should be to have a proxy that give access to a concrete authentication key. this is supponse that users have to get a certificate?

Comment: A certificate, a password, any authentication setup would work as long as the app could be distributed with the "keys to the castle" embedded in it. Client certificates would indeed work very well for that, because you could issue a certificate per device and have fine-grained control over which devices are still allowed to access the services.

Comment: I would recommend you reformat your question and ask it over on ServerFault, by the way. There are great folks over there who can help you in setting up a suitable proxy server. Then, you could ask a new SO question about building an app that uses the proxy server to get onto the internet (or some parts of the company's internal network).

Answer (score 2):

If you want to provide only app to connect to any network then you need to put some rules in `IPTABLES in linux` core (`this needs your application to have root access`) just like the `firewall applications` for android that monitors **UIDs** of applications accessing network

But you can do it the other way, implement some server calls that the particular network of the company will only be accessed through that particular app, Use some validation in http requests such as maintain a `unique ID` to differentiate your app/user that you can create during registration and during interacting with the network `use the key for validation`.

Comment: His question is tagged both Android and iPhone. An (unjailbroken) iPhone doesn't have any way of regulating which apps access what on which networks AFAIK.

Comment: yep, but can work full proof in android, my solution mainly focuses on android part of the application. I doubt it can seriously be possible on iphone as there are plenty of restrictions.

Comment: thanks. The app could only use Internet service INTo the app, for example to send a mail to company or fill a form.

Comment: on android, if you set such rules then this can be achieved, you can find similar implementation in Firewall apps on linux machines!!